# how to handle 404 or page not found error in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, http-status-code-404, coldfusion-8

in coldfusion how to handle 404 error or page not found error, what will be the code to show custom error message in case any requested page is not found.

Thanks,
Yugal

Comment: There is a tutorial on coldfusion error handling, have a look at http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfu...ebugError5.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. In IIS or Apache, change the default 404 error handler to point to a cfm file of your choice.
2. In Application.cfc, set up the onMissingTemplate function to handle requests for .cfm files that are sent to ColdFusion before the web server checks to see if they actually exist.

Dan

Comment: This is a very old thread, but I am having similar issue with CF on Plesk.   How can the onMissingTemplate be implemented?  I asked the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68751151/how-to-handle-404-page-on-multiple-coldfusion-domains-under-plesk  Thanks.